# Menu 3 dots are not showing

Tags: java, android, xml

```
package com.example.project131;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    TextView mProfileTv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mProfileTv = findViewById(R.id.profileTv);
    }

    private void checkUserStatus(){
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(user != null){
            mProfileTv.setText(user.getEmail());
        }
        else{
            startActivity(new 
Intent(ProfileActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        checkUserStatus();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_logout){
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            checkUserStatus();
           }
        return true;
       }
    }
```

this is xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item android:id="@+id/action_logout"
  android:title="Logout"
     />
    </menu>
```

I  tried with many methods and also adding showActions methods in xml files, but not works.
I  tried with many methods and also adding showActions methods in xml files, but not works. 
I  tried with many methods and also adding showActions methods in xml files, but not works.
Please help me.

Comment: please anyone help me i am trying this thing from past 4 days please

Comment: What version of Android are you on?

Comment: emulator 29  physical device 25

Comment: please help please i got frustration

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me:

```
<item
        item android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:title="Logout"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item android:id="@+id/action_logout"
  app:showAsAction="always"
  android:title="Logout"/>
  </menu>
```